# how to integrate algorithm written in C# onto an android application project that written in Java?

Tags: c#, midi, steganography

I got a big problem in integrating some steganography algorithm that written in C# onto my android project, anybody got any idea how to do so? My android project is steganography in MIDI files and the only algorithm I found is written in C#. Please help me.

Comment: Learn the language and rewrite it yourself as needed? Or you're searching for some automated tool or something? Don't understand what's exactly your problem.

Comment: If can, I want automated tool because I don't have any idea how to start the algorithm integration onto my project.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsc.sourceforge.net/. Try this